# <nolink> not working with iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, drupal, menu

I have a website where I use a dropdown with no parent menu point, see: http://wittmerperformance.com/site
Now, i just got told that the empty dropdown (SERVICES) doesn't work with the iPad. I unfortunately don't have an iPad to verify.

Could someone let me know how I can make this showing up on iPad properly too?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't surprise me, I am having issues on my iPhone with iOS6 as well.  Typically, you need to still do a,  then set the href="#" for it to work on touch screen devices, since then it creates a zone that the user can click creating a pseudo hover/active state that then triggers the drop down.

So:

```
<a href="#">Services</a>
```

Instead of your `<span>.`

Comment: Only Drupal doesn't let me set the path to "#". I get Notice: Undefined index: path in menu_edit_item_validate() (line 391 of /home/content/86/9316986/html/site/sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart-7.x-1.7/modules/menu/menu.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: path in menu_edit_item_validate() (line 392 of /home/content/86/9316986/html/site/sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart-7.x-1.7/modules/menu/menu.admin.inc).
The path '' is either invalid or you do not have access to it. :(

Comment: I am not well versed in Drupal, but if I go to you site and simply add a '#' to the url's it works, so not sure why it won't allow it.  Anyways, you will want to use a jquery solution then, there are many options for it and many explinations of how to implement them... pretty simple, simply going to be such that ontouch mouse-event hover is triggered for that element.  this should help http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/

Comment: Uh, it doesn't let me add a '#' either... :( anyone an idea how to do this in Drupal? Otherwise, I guess I'll check how to do it the JQuery way - i'll also have to figure out how and where the menu gets created .... :)

Comment: I linked you to a tutorial on how to do it with jquery.